# Heroku Create: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

Trying to deploy my first Rails app to Heroku.

All app code is here:
https://github.com/donpinkus/first_app.

Running `heroku create` gives me this error:

```
donaldmbp15:first_app donald$ git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.132' to the list of known hosts.
Connection closed by 50.19.85.132
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
donaldmbp15:first_app donald$
```

It sounds like something along the line, either Heroku or Github does not have access rights. I've pushed to Github from my local git repo, so I'm ruling out Github as the source of error. That leaves Heroku, or my local machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you try pushing from your local machine? You just need the https://toolbelt.heroku.com - Heroku Toolbelt, and you can push the repo from your local machine?

Comment: The error you shared is not from `heroku create`. What does `git remote -v` show? Does the `heroku` remote match up with the git repository from `heroku info`?

Comment: @RickPeck - I am pushing from my local machine :)

Comment: @catsby - this is the output from `git remote -v` donaldmbp15:demo_app donald$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/donpinkus/demo_app.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/donpinkus/demo_app.git (push)
donaldmbp15:demo_app donald$

Comment: That shows you don't have a `heroku` git remote. suggest you read this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Answer (score 1):

First Generate the RSA key first by following

```
bash: ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Add your key to heroku

```
bash: heroku keys:add
```

Read more https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys